# How quickly do new molds reach PAB on the Lego website?

Tags: piece-information

A few months ago, I asked Lego customer service if the 1x2 jumper plates on the Lego PAB site would be the new mould (with stud holders) or the old mould (with pegs).  I received no reply, not even to say that they didn't know.

If anyone has ordered 1x2 jumpers or 2x2 round tiles recently, did you receive the new moulds or the old ones?

How long does it take for the new moulds to hit the Pick a Brick bins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that is unanswerable except in very vague terms like "some time after the new molds get put into production" and "it will be a LONG time before the old ones go away completely".

Comment: Unfortunately, I would have to agree, I might just have to order three of each colour periodically and see what I get.